# Wordpress admin_ini declared in theme and plugin, breaks

Tags: php, wordpress

I ran into a problem with a new, off the shelf, wordpress theme I just finished customizing. When I install it on my production machine (with many plugins) the site throws an error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare admin_init()

along with the path to the two instances. When I look them up, I see this function declared in a theme file:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_init');
function admin_init()
{....
```

and this one declared in a plugin file:

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
function admin_init(){...
```

Obviously the error states this is not allowed. But my question is, what is the **best** way to fix this so both the theme and plugin get what they need to work? In this case, I would define "best" as the solution that will require the least amount of babysitting when it comes to updates (of the plugin and theme...thought the plugin is likely to be updated more frequently than the theme).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a WordPress theme, [the Codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review#Theme_Namespacing):

> Themes are required to use a unique slug as a prefix for anything in
>   the public namespace, including all custom function names, classes,
>   hooks, public/global variables, database entries (Theme options, post
>   custom metadata, etc.)

So, the standard solution to the problem would be to use a unique slug to prefix the public function, based on the name of the theme.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_theme_slug_admin_init');
function my_theme_slug_admin_init()
{....
```

If you're familiar with PHP classes, and OOP in general, one approach that people use to minimise changes (and typing out slugs!) is to wrap custom functions up in a class. That approach (as described [here](http://hardcorewp.com/2012/using-classes-as-code-wrappers-for-wordpress-plugins/) and to some degree in [the answers to this (slightly annoyed!) question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/using-oop-in-themes) encapsulates your custom functions in a class, so only the class name itself appears in the global namespace.